# using {{ }} in local script became error in google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using `{{ }}` and `{{{ }}}` symbols in my script but when I deliver this script in GTM it became error.
Is there any solution to use this symbols and avoid error?

This is an example code which has been error

```
'     <ul class="test">' +
"       {{#display}}" +
'       <li class="content">' +
```

Thanks in advance.

I changed `{{` to `"& #123;"` and `"& #125;"` but it did not work.

in google tag manager it recognize as variable if I use the code above in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can escape the curly braces, like this:

```
'     <ul class="test">' +
"       \{\{#display\}\}" +
'       <li class="content">' ;
```

This will be processed by GTM.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it and it worked out. However if I bundle script by using webpack, escaping with backslash disappeared. So currently I have to escape everytime when I bundle my script. Do you have any idea or solution to avoid to escape everytime when I bundle??

Comment: Sorry, I could answer only the GTM part, not the webpack part.